# scanf to read multiple data types from one input

Tags: c, types, scanf

So I am trying to read in an equation in the form `mx+b=y`. How do I use `scanf` to read multiple data types? I've tried using something like:

```
scanf(" %d %c %c %d %c %d", &num1, &variable, &sign, &num2, &equal_sign, &num3);
```

In this format it reads `num1` correctly but somehow skips assigning the first character to variable and instead puts it in sign. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It seems like no special problem. Show indicate the input example to fail.

Comment: which compiler you are using ? I am getting expected results here in devC++ and in GNU GCC version 4.8.1 ...

Comment: Provide example input.