# Using scanf with multiple data types

Tags: c, gcc, types, scanf

I am trying to read in an equation in the form of mx+b=y where m, b, and y are integers and x is a character. How do I read in both integers and characters and check that the user inputs the data in that exact form. That is, I somehow need to check that the user inputs a '+' sign an '=' sign and uses the correct variable. eg) I want it to accept mx+b=y but not mX+b=y or another example: accept mx+b=y but not mx-b=y. And I also need it to ignore any additional input after the equation.

I've tried using something like:

scanf(" %d %c %c %d %c %d", &m, &x, &sign, &b, &equal_sign, &y);

Using this format it reads in the first number correctly but skips putting the next character into the variable x and instead puts it in sign.

Sorry for the lengthy wording but I'd appreciate any help and just let me know if I need to clarify anything. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697549/scanf-to-read-multiple-data-types-from-one-input

Answer (score 4):

I would read the entire line using [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or perhaps [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) then manually parse the buffer containing the line, using [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) with a given end pointer, or [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) (explicitly testing the returned count, and perhaps using the `%n` format specifier).

You might want to [parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) an expression into an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), e.g. using some [recursive descent parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) technique. See also the [infix-calc example of GNU bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Infix-Calc.html)

If you are sure that your input is *exactly* of the form *a* `x +` *b* `=` *c*  (which is unnatural for `3x+-5=8`, since you want to type just `3x-5=8`) you could use a mix of `strtol`. See also [strncmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncmp.3.html) and [strtok(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html)

<sup>PS. Follow *all* the links I am giving you here. They are *all* relevant!</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Get the equation in string format(buffer) and parse this buffer using the sscanf function. By using scanf function there may be a problem of flush kind of things

Comment: -1: this doesn't really answer the question - you should at least provide a simple code example to illustrate what you're trying to say.

Answer (score -1):

when you got input prompt , you should try to input **one value** than **tab** than **another value** than tab..and so on .until you entered all values.

scanf(" %d %c %c %d %c %d", &m, &x, &sign, &b, &equal_sign, &y);

first value you entered will be assign to m,
after press tab
second value will be assign to x
press tab..

do this until you entered all values..

Comment: -1: this doesn't really answer the question - you should at least provide a simple code example to illustrate what you're trying to say.

Comment: The thing is I can't expect the user to input the equation in any one certain form. If they input it incorrectly I want to return an error, but if they input it correctly, including the correct variable, and '+' and '=' sign, I want to accept it.

Comment: you need to use if / else or switch case for desired variable..and if that variable does not meet our requirement, ask for input again to user...

like
scanf();

if(x!='X')
{scan again}